# Which model of computation can be viewed as being extended by the currently most relevant models of quantum computation?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, models, computer

Which model of quantum computation resembles most closely the attempts of implementation currently being made?

And which non-quantum model of computation is the conceptually closest one to the above model??